# Spring Boot microservice , black list/exclude list of ports

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, microservices

Requirement - Is there any way via configuration/custom logic  to provide a blacklist ports configuration so sprint boot service will never pick those ports when it starts, this is required as some of our legacy services runs in dedicated ports and those services starts after our spring boot application starts, if spring boot application picks those ports then it will create a clash.

example : we are looking for something like below , where we can exclude these ports so they will never be picked up by spring boot application.
**exclude.ports= 18080,28080**

Comment: Isn't setting the port that you want to be used enough in this case?

Comment: No you can't do that. The selection of a random port number is made by the OS from the ephemeral port range when the socket is bound and then Tomcat asks the OS which one was selected. If your other services require fixed ports and you own the server then why not fix the port of your spring boot service as well?

Comment: We dont want to hardcode the port , reason is to facilitate HA(High Availibity-  if there is more load on specific day we can spun off multiple instance of same service) .   My Solution: Do you think that passing the port as an argument will suffice, i can create a small external job (  run before spring boot app) and whose task is to find a  open port ( in rare instance if random port found is in our  excluded  port list , it will search again t until it is not present in excluded list) and pass this as an args when we start the Spring boot application.

Comment: Yes, passing the port on the command line would be a workable compromise for you. Do not include that server's ephemeral range in your search because they are randomly selected for use as the local end of server connections and you run the risk of a race condition between your test for in-use and your server starting.